# How to prevent user from modifying submitted value in the form?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a simple form that sends a value to controller:

```
<form action="{{route('mollie.payment')}}" method="post"  >
@csrf
{{--    <input name="text" type="text">--}}


<button type="submit"  name="test" value="23.00">Send</button>
</form>
```

This value will be static and this value cannot be modified.  But of course it can be easily changed in Chrome dev tools.

How can I better implement this?

I though of doing validation like this:

```
   public function preparePayment(Request $request)
   {
    
    $this->validate($request,[
        'test' => '230.00'
    ]);
...
```

But it doesn't work:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate230.00 does not exist.
```

What is good way of securing this value?

Comment: If it's static and won't be modified why not define it in a variable in your controller?

Comment: Yes, why is it even a part of the form?

Comment: if it is some kind of token then reject said value if it has been changed and is not valid. If this value is something like price or something like that then calculate it in your controller instead of taking it from form. Prices on front side should only be for display and not for calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of laravel form request to validate request payload.

You can create new form request via command

```
php artisan make:request StorePaymentRequest
```

Then goto newly created file in app\Http\Requests folder and write all the rules in here.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\StorePaymentRequest;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;=

class GetPayoutRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'status' => 'numeric|between:23.00,23.00'
    }
}
```

Use this StorePaymentRequest in `preparePayment` controller method.

```
public function preparePayment(StorePaymentRequest $request)
{
    $requestPayload = $request->validated();
    dd($requestPayload);
}
```

Now, request will be able to come up here if it successfully passed the validation otherwise `ValidationException` will be thrown automatically.